# Script to check IIS running or not

Tags: iis, monitoring

I would like to write a script to start IIS server automatically if it is stopped.

Comment: sc qc w3svc, sc config (check help to see how to change restart options etc). Windows services can be configured to restart automatically on fail with indefinite retries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IIS Admin Scripts to query the server, and then start it if you need.

The script is located in `%systemroot%\system32`.

To query you server, just run `IIsWeb.vbs /query w3svc/1` from a command line.

If it's not running, then you can run `IIsWeb.vbs /start w3svc/1` to start it.

Here is an [article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aee71684-36c0-40e1-b387-a19d2d0509f0.mspx?mfr=true) with more information on these scripts.

Comment: `IIsWeb.vbs` does not exist on Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score 1):

- you can look for w3wp.exe in the process list (if it's IIS6)
- you can always try "iisreset /start"  - I believe, it works even if IIS is already started
- take a look at the scripts provided by Microsoft in `C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts` (assuming default install location), there is startsrv.vbs, startweb.vbs - both do a good job

Comment: that is only if the service is currently active, that does not check if it is running

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing you can do if you are worried about iis not restarting after it fails is to set the services responses.  If you go into services and then look at the properties for iis, you will see a recovery tab.  Change each of the failure options to restart the service.  one thing you could also do is create a batch file that includes 
iisreset 
and set the option to run program and have that be the program you select.

Answer (score 0):

Found some code here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a01d88b-2b7c-4d0b-bce0-9b90a236b64a/how-to-check-if-iis-is-running?forum=asmxandxml

Example:

```
Dim sc As New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("World Wide Web Publishing Service")

If sc.Status.Equals(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or sc.Status.Equals(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
   ' Start the service if the current status is stopped.
   sc.Start()
Else
   ' Stop the service if its status is not set to "Stopped".
   sc.Stop()
End If
```